# how to divide column and this following in a data frame

Tags: r

I tried to create a function that divide every column by this following in data frame for example if I have a data frame like that:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
```

I would like to create a function that divide col1 by col2, col3 by col4 ....col(n-1) by col(n) to the end of the data frame and print a data frame that bind all the output lists.

I created a function that divide column and this following but isn't a loop function.

```
bigfunction<-function(data,n){
  n<-1
    data[,1]
    data[,n+1]
    d<-(data[,n]/data[,n+1])
   print(as.list(d))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectorise that calculation!

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9, d = 10:12)

df[c(1,3)]/df[c(2,4)]
#     a         c
#1 0.25 0.7000000
#2 0.40 0.7272727
#3 0.50 0.7500000

divdf <- function(data) {
  data[seq(1,ncol(data),2)]/data[seq(2,ncol(data),2)]
}
divdf(df)
#     a         c
#1 0.25 0.7000000
#2 0.40 0.7272727
#3 0.50 0.7500000
```

You could add some further error checking to this to make sure you always have an even number of columns etc, but this is the basic logic that you can add to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
fun1 <- function(df){
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    if (i%%2 == 1){next}
    else{
      temp <- df[, i-1]/df[, i]
      temp_df <- cbind(temp_df, temp)
    }
  }

  return(temp_df)
}

df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9, d = 10:12)
temp_df <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(df))
new_df <- fun1(df)
```

I have created a temporary dataframe to keep `cbind`ing the vectors. You can remove the `id` column later on and change the column names as per requirement. This assumes that you have an even number of columns (if not then it will simply ignore the last one)